# How to store different users images or files in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to build a website that stores different users data like images and file. I know how to store stuff in s3 but how do i store different users data so they are the only ones that can access it and they can access someone else's data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your definition of a "user" means "application user", then you should definitely not give them IAM credentials (which are only for your own staff).

Instead, your application should do the following:

- **Authenticate** users to know who they are (eg with Amazon Cognito or an identity store)
- Keep all objects in Amazon S3 **private**
- When a user wants to access a private object, your application should determine **whether they should be permitted access** (based on information in your own database and business logic)
- If they *are* permitted access, the application should **generate a Pre-Signed URL** which provides time-limited access to the private object
- The application can embed the Pre-Signed URL in an HTML page, such as in an `<img>` tag
- When Amazon S3 receives the request for the object, it will **validate** the URL and, if it is correct, will provide access to the object
- If anyone tries to use the Pre-Signed URL after the expiry period, the link will not work

It only takes a couple of lines of code to create a Pre-Signed URL, and does not require a call back to AWS.

See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep your S3 bucket private and create a specific folder (a file prefix) for each user. Then you can manage access by using [signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) with custom policies. Your application manages access to this bucket by creating signed URLS per user.

You can use custom policies and specify a wildcard resource path. Not that IP address below is optional.

```
{
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Resource":"http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/myuser/*",
         "Condition":{
            "IpAddress":{"AWS:SourceIp":"192.0.0.14/32"},
            "DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":1357034400}
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IAM Policies to grant access to user-specific folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket

use `aws:username`

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
      "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","home/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
      "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":
                  [
                       "home/${aws:username}/*",
                       "home/${aws:username}"
                  ]
               }
        }
    },
    {
       "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
       "Action":["s3:*"],
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company/home/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

For more info follow link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

To upload file in dir use `key` while calling `putObject` or `upload`

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var s3Client = new AWS.S3();

var params = { Bucket: 'your_bucket_goes_here', Key: 'folderInBucket/', ACL: 'public-read', Body:'body does not matter' };

s3Client.upload(params, function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.log("Error creating the folder: ", err);
    } else {
    console.log("Successfully created a folder on S3");

    }
});
```

Comment: as an example the arlo camera store you video in its ow folder inside s3 how do i do something like that it has like an access key in the url when looking at it with dev console in chrome?         something like this https://arlos3-prod-z2.s3.amazonaws.com/310c0f4e_674a_48c7_a857_b76cc226b047/DR9C-336-32372083/52M17C7GA01B2/recordings/1566780991986.mp4

Comment: Use `putObject` with `key=myfolder/subfolder/`. Updated answer